# How can I include values in my javascript populated drop down list to include in a price calculator?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code sample:

```
    <script>
    const td=new Date();               // set Date object td to today
    const timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
    td.setDate(td.getDate()+3)
    ndays = td - new Date();
    let deadline = td.toLocaleTimeString([], {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'});
    document.cookie = "ndays = " + ndays;
    offset = td.getTimezoneOffset();
    const opts=[...Array(18)].map(_=>{  // generate an Array of 7 (empty) elements
    let r=td.toLocaleString("en-us",{weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric'}) + " @ "+deadline+" "+timezone+" Time ("+ Math.round(ndays/60/60/24/1000) + " days)"; // format date td
     td.setDate(td.getDate()+1);       // increment td by one calendar day
     ndays = td - new Date();
     return r                          // return date string to opts array 
      })
     </script>
    <select name="deadline" id="deadline" class="form-control" required="required">             
    <script>
    document.querySelector("select").innerHTML=opts.map(o=>`<option>${o}</option>`).join("") // make options
    </script>
    </select>
```

I need to be able to add incremented values based on the deadline selected to include in a pricing calculation. For example, if the order is:

- 15 or more days: the price would be $10 per unit (a factor of 1)
- 10 to 14 days: it would be $12 per unit (a factor of 1.2)
- 7 days: $13 per unit (a factor of 1.3)
- 5 days: $14 (a factor of 1.4)
- 3 days: $15 (a factor of 1.5)

Comment: Doesn't strike me as something you'd do "in the dropdown". Don't see what extra data you'd include. This strikes me as being business logic, rather than item prices. As such, I'd expect to handle selection of items with a function. In that function, I'd look at how many days were selected, decide on a factor and then reflect this decision by updating some variable. It'd probably help if the code in the question was able to be run here on the page.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I'll see what I can do about getting a snippet to run. I'm new at posting. So, thanks again. I'll try to implement your suggestion to the best of my ability. Javascript is not my strong suit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `document.querySelector("select").innerHTML` to write a string of the options to the `<select>` element. First add the days to the `opts` array:

```
const opts=[...Array(18)].map(_=>{
    let numdays = Math.round(ndays/60/60/24/1000);
    //...
    ndays = td - new Date();
    return [numdays, r];
});
```

...then, when looping it, add the days to the option value and text to the option element:

```
document.querySelector("select").innerHTML = opts.map(([d,o])=>`<option value="${d}">${o}</option>`).join("");
```

Use the `document.querySelector("select")` `change` event listener to implement your pricing calculator.

---

All together:

```js
// WRITE DATE OPTIONS ARRAY
const opts = writeDateOptions();

// WRITE DATE OPTIONS TO SELECT ELEMENT
const sel = document.getElementById("deadline");
sel.innerHTML = "<option></option>" + opts.map(([d,o])=>`<option value="${d}">${o}</option>`).join("");

// GET DAYS AND FACTOR ON SELECT CHANGE EVENT
sel.addEventListener("change", function (evt) {
  let days = parseInt(evt.target.options[evt.target.selectedIndex].value);
  let factor = 0;
  switch (days) {
    case 3: case 4: factor = 1.5; break;
    case 5: case 6: factor = 1.4; break;
    case 7: case 8: case 9: factor = 1.3; break;
    case 10: case 11: case 12: case 13: case 14: factor = 1.2; break;
    case 15: default: factor = 1.0;
  }
  // price calculator here?
  document.getElementById("daysfactor").innerText 
    = days + " days, "
    + factor + " factor";
});

// this is a simply a function wrapped around the date/options array code to be able to move it to the bottom of the code so as to emphasize the bulk of the additional code
function writeDateOptions () {

  const td=new Date(); // set Date object td to today
  const timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
  td.setDate(td.getDate()+3);
  ndays = td - new Date();
  let deadline = td.toLocaleTimeString([], {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'});
  //document.cookie = "ndays = " + ndays; // stackoverflow doesn't like no one messin' with her cookies
  offset = td.getTimezoneOffset();

  // return days/desc options array
  return [...Array(18)].map(_=>{
    let numdays = Math.round(ndays/60/60/24/1000);
    let r=td.toLocaleString(
      "en-us", {weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric'}
    ) + " @ "+deadline+" "+timezone+" Time ("+ numdays + " days)"; // format date td
    td.setDate(td.getDate()+1); // increment td by one calendar day
    ndays = td - new Date();

    return [numdays, r]; // return days and date string to opts array 
  });

}
```

```html
<select name="deadline" id="deadline" class="form-control" required="required"></select>
<div id="daysfactor"></div>
```

OR, create each option element and add the value and text content while looping your dates array.

```js
// replace vvvv
// document.querySelector("select").innerHTML = opts.map(([d,o])=>`<option value="${d}">${o}</option>`).join("");
// with vvvv


// ADD OPTIONS WITH VALUES AND TEXT TO SELECT
const sel = document.querySelector("select");
sel.appendChild(document.createElement("option")); // blank option first
opts.forEach(function ([numdays, desc]) {
  let opt = document.createElement("option");
  opt.value = numdays;
  opt.textContent = desc;
  sel.appendChild(opt);
});
```

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks a bunch. I'll keep you posted as attempt implementation.